# Apple iOS Ad Hoc Distribution Legality Standard License

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am not finding a definitive answer on this topic and Google searches tend to say both things but here is my question.  I see some websites saying that they distribute their applications to customers, usually for testing, before pushing to the AppStore through Ad-Hoc distribution.  My understanding is that Ad-Hoc distribution is for testing, meaning that it is **not** ok to distribute to "anyone".  Is it ok to release applications this way to anyone?  Does the phrase Ad-Hoc distribution imply "testing".  This phrase is confusing.  The 100 device cap seems really high if you are a one man team or even a small group, does this suggest that you can distribute through Ad-Hoc to anyone?  Below is part of section 7.2 from the program license agreement under Apple's standard iOS license:

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, You may also distribute Your Applications 
>   to individuals within Your company, organization, educational institution, group, or who are 
>   otherwise affiliated with You for use solely on a limited number of Registered Devices (as 
>   specified on the Program web portal), if Your Application has been digitally signed using Your 
>   Apple-issued digital certificate as described in this Agreement.  By distributing Your Application in 
>   this manner, You represent and warrant to Apple that Your Application complies with the 
>   Documentation and Program Requirements then in effect and You agree to cooperate with Apple 
>   and to answer questions and provide information about Your Application, as reasonably 
>   requested by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Distributing applications to your clients so that they can test the application is part of **testing**

Services like [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com) use ad-hoc distribution to ease the distribution of your apps to clients and testers.

Ad-hoc distributions let you send the app to a device that is registered to your developer account. 100 devices is really not a lot.

Comment: Ok, great.  So do you know if the intent of Ad-Hoc is for only testing?  Or can this be a final release to anyone (granted you only get 100 devices per year)?

Comment: That's up to you. But it's not 100 devices per year. It's 100 devices in total.